# Convert datetime to include utc timezone php

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to convert datetime to a UTC timecode using PHP, how do I convert 2022-05-14 13:30:30 so it will come out as 2022-05-14T13:30:30+01:00

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format can be obtained with the method `toAtomString()`. With my timezone settings, i got the timezone `02:00`, so i had to use `setTimezone()` and specifying the timezone on the parsing. Can be left out, if yours is correct.

```
Carbon::parse('2022-05-14 13:30:30', 'Europe/london')
    ->setTimezone('Europe/london')
    ->toAtomString();
```

This will format the date as follows `2022-05-14T13:30:30+01:00`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution with DateTime:

```
$date = date_create('2022-05-14 13:30:30', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'))
  ->format(DateTimeInterface::ATOM);

echo $date;  //2022-05-14T13:30:30+01:00
```

Try [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/kkgWW).